# Paging with CosmosClient in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to implement paging using the SDK v3 `CosmosClient` instead of the old `DocumentClient`.

Reason for this is it seems `DocumentClient` doesn't translate LINQ queries that contains spatial functions very well (ie: When using `Within()` I'll get an error from DocumentClient stating the methods is not implemented).

Paging works well with `DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>` as such:

```
var query = DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("master", "features"), feedOptions)
                .Where(t => t.Type == typeof(T).Name)
                .Where(pred)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

string queryContinuationToken = null;
var page = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
if (query.HasMoreResults)
    queryContinuationToken = page.ResponseContinuation;
```

I'm at a little loss as to where to gather a continuation token using `CosmosClient` and its `Container` class:

```
QueryRequestOptions options = new QueryRequestOptions();
options.MaxItemCount = maxRecords;

FeedIterator<T> feed;

if (continuationToken == "")
    feed = Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, null, options).Where(x => x.Type == typeof(T).Name).Where(pred).ToFeedIterator();
else
    feed = Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, continuationToken, options).Where(x => x.Type == typeof(T).Name).Where(pred).ToFeedIterator();
```

`FeedIterator` seems to have some of the members `IDocumentQuery` has (like `HasMoreResults`) but I can't find a continuation token anywhere.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this section about `FetchNextSetAsync()`: "[Reading many items from the container](https://joonasw.net/view/exploring-cosmos-db-sdk-v3)" useful?

Comment: @Crowcoder Seems out of date already. CosmosClient has no Database member, Container has no Items member.

Comment: if u use order by we r getting error while passing token for next apge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, here's a `Where` method I implemented. Seems to work at first glance.

If you do `var f = feed.ReadNextAsync()` you won't get an object that's of type `FeedResponse`, preventing you access to the token. You need to declare `f` explicitly of type `FeedResponse<T>`

```
public async Task<(IEnumerable<T> Results, string ContinuationToken)> Where<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> pred, int maxRecords = 0, string partitionKey = "", string continuationToken = "") where T : IDocumentModel
{

    QueryRequestOptions options = new QueryRequestOptions();

    if (partitionKey != "")
        options.PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey);


    if (maxRecords == 0)
    {
        return (Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, null, options).Where(x => x.Type == typeof(T).Name).Where(pred), "");
    }
    else
    {
        options.MaxItemCount = maxRecords;
        string token = "";
        FeedIterator<T> feed;
        List<T> res = new List<T>();

        if (continuationToken == "")
            feed = Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, null, options).Where(x => x.Type == typeof(T).Name).Where(pred).ToFeedIterator();
        else
            feed = Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, continuationToken, options).Where(x => x.Type == typeof(T).Name).Where(pred).ToFeedIterator();

        Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.FeedResponse<T> f = await feed.ReadNextAsync();
        token = f.ContinuationToken;

        foreach (var item in f)
        {
            res.Add(item);
        }

        return (res, token);
    }

}
```

Comment: How to implement Orderby?

Answer (score 3):

With the version 3.12.0 of the Cosmos SDK the following works as expected as a pretty much in place replacement for the older DocumentQuery.

Original DocumentClient method for comparison:

```
IDocumentQuery<ToDoItem> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<ToDoItem>(collectionUri)
            .Where(t => t.Description.Contains(searchterm))
            .AsDocumentQuery();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
  foreach (ToDoItem result in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
  {
    log.LogInformation(result.Description);
  }
}
```

Using a CosmosClient this becomes:

```
var database = client.GetDatabase("ToDoItems");
var container = database.GetContainer("Items");

var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<ToDoItem>()
     .Where(t => t.Description.Contains(searchTerm))
     .ToFeedIterator();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
  foreach (ToDoItem result in await query.ReadNextAsync())
  {
    log.LogInformation(result.Description);
  }    
}
```

So your query is now a `FeedIterator`, and you can call `HasMoreResults` and `ReadNextAsync` on it.

Admittedly this won't get you access to the diagnostics, request charge, etc. that comes on the FeedIterator, but it will page through the results cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

```
IQueryable<returnVModel> query;
var requestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions
{
 MaxItemCount = 20
};
if (Token == "" || Token == null)
{
      query = Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<returnVModel>(false, null, requestOptions).Where(x => x.id == id);
 }
 else
 {
      query = Container.GetItemLinqQueryable<returnVModel>(false, Token, requestOptions).Where(x => x.id == id);
 }
 var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
 var totalCount = await query.CountAsync(ct.Token); //Total Count
 var feedIterator = query.ToFeedIterator();
 var queryResults = new List<returnVModel>();
 FeedResponse<returnVModel> feedResults = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(ct.Token);
 queryResults.AddRange(feedResults); // Output
 var PaginationToken = feedResults.ContinuationToken //Token
```

First time we need to pass token as null, from next page onwards pass the token which we received in previous output.

Pagination was working fine in v3.

Comment: @Francis Ducharme Whether we will get any performance issue like that when we move to production?